# Cannot find module 'mysql' require stack

Tags: javascript, mysql-connector

[Issue I am running into](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k50CH.png)

I have run `npm install mysql` and `npm install -g mysql` and `npm install mysql --save` in an attempt to fix the issue with no luck.

I have also double checked that the module is showing up in my node_modules/ directory.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you check where do you have your `node_modules/` directory?

I mean:

```
./node_modules/node-mysql/node_modules/
```

or maybe

```
./node_modules/
```

or maybe

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/
```

`npm install -g mysql` installs **globally**, not locally. Modules are put into  `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`, and puts executable files go to `/usr/local/bin`.

`npm install mysql` installs **locally**. This installs your package in the current working directory. Node modules go in `./node_modules`, executables go in `./node_modules/.bin/`. And that means the script you are running needs to be run from the same directory containing node_modules.

Comment: That was it. For some reason the MySQL install wasn't installing into the right folder. I cd'd into it and did a manual install in that directory and it fixed my issue. Thank you.